# Is there a fast way to send bitcoins to an address on a web page?

Tags: websites, payment

I'm looking for something like a browser extensions that makes it possible to easily send bitcoins to an address on a web page.

I don't think a `bitcoin:[address]` URI protocol already lifted off, otherwise it would be ideal. But as long as it doesn't, a browser extension would be good enough...

Comment: `bitcoin:` links open in multibit automatically for me. (Using chrome.)

Comment: Does the original Bitcoin client supports that as well?

Comment: @StevenRoose Yes.

Comment: Oh, just found this one. See my related question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10863/4975